# CakePHP 3 edit form isn't being populated with database object

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.8

I've built a fair number of applications in CakePHP which have edit (Update) functionality. I've come across an issue which I haven't had before where Cake isn't populating a set of form fields even though the data is being returned from the database and the field names match.

In a Controller method I am obtaining data:

```
public function edit() 
{
    $invno = '1234'; // This is dynamic from the URL but is here for the example

    $TblInvoicestobepaid = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('TblInvoicestobepaid');
    $data = $TblInvoicestobepaid->find()->where(
            ['invno' => $invno]
        );
    if (!$data->isEmpty()) {
        $data = $data->first();
    }

}
```

If I do `debug($data);` I can see that the data is being returned from the database and is an Object:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\TblInvoicestobepaid) {

'invno' => '1234',
'amount' => '1090',
'vat' => '218',
'total' => '1308',
'orgname' => 'Test Company',

}
```

I have then used `$this->set(compact('data'));` to pass this data to my template. This seems the same as other Controller `edit()` methods including those that have been baked.

I'm using the Form Helper and the field names match the keys in the object above, e.g.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->text('invno'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->text('amount'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->text('vat'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->text('total'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->text('orgname'); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

The form is rendered but the fields are empty.

One thing I did notice is that this is a legacy application and the table where this data is obtained from doesn't have an `id` field. The Primary Key is `invno` and this is a string (`varchar` in MySQL). But this has been defined in the Table class:

```
// src/Model/Table/TblInvoicestobepaidTable.php
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('tbl_invoicestobepaid');
    $this->setDisplayField('invno');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('invno');
}
```

I don't have any problems inserting data through the `add()` method in my Controller. But when it comes to editing it's not populating the form, and I don't understand why.

CakePHP version is 3.8.12

Comment: `$this->set("inv_data" , $data) ;`  instead of compact... Then debug on view...

Comment: Where's the rest of the form, specifically the `FormHelper::create()` call?

Comment: @ndm I've updated the form code. It submits to the current controller action, i.e. `edit()`

Comment: You're not passing the entity to the form (first argument of `FormHelper::create()`, hence it's not picking up any values.

Comment: From the first comment. Set data to "inv_data" var and next set it to form ```<?php echo $this->Form->create($inv_data); ?>```